# ArrayBlockingQueue: should use to create Pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I'm trying to create a `Pool` object to reserve old objects in case of use them again (to avoid instantiation of new objects). I google that `ArrayBlockingQueue` and some people use it to create `Pool`. But there is one question I don't know: does it recreate a new instance when an object insert to it.

For example: `ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> pool = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(3);`

after short time: `pool = (3,4,5);`

```
pool.take(5); ==> pool = (3,4);
pool.put(6);  ==>pool = (6,3,4);
```

So, I wonder is 6 assigned to the old Integer object (with value 5), or does Java create a new one and assign it's value as 6?

thanks :)

Comment: the question was very unclear, so I suggested some editing to the best of my understanding. Hope I did not misunderstand your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ArrayBlockingQueue` is backed by an array of the parameter type. So internally it would look something like this:

```
E[] items;
```

and instantiated in your case as

```
Integer[] items;
```

According to the [source code](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue-source.html) of `ArrayBlockingQueue`, the `put` method actually calls this `insert` method:

```
private void insert(E x) {
    items[putIndex] = x;
    putIndex = inc(putIndex);
    ++count;
    notEmpty.signal();
}
```

So what happens when you call `pool.put(6)` is that the `int` 6 is boxed into an `Integer` object and passed to the method (since `E` is now `Integer`). So it's safe to say that indeed it does create a new instance of `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

See you shouldn't worry about the underlying implementation, that is what is intended in java by "encapsulation". According to the Oracle docs, "put" actually "inserts" the element at the tail. So there isn't any replacement of "old objects", i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously doubt that any replacing of values would be actual in this case. Furthermore, I am not sure having a custom implementation of such an object pool would be useful, unless your code generates and trashes an immense number of objects.

What's more interesting is that you do not mention anything about thread safety or multithreading in your question, but you have used these tags. What exactly is it that you want to achieve with such a pool? `ArrayBlockingQueue` is intended as a thread-safe collection where one (or many) threads dump in objects while one (or many) threads remove objects out. There are quite a few methods to supply different behaviors in case an objects is required from the queue but there is none, or when an objects is added but there is no capacity in the queue. You should check out the [javadoc](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html&ei=h-IzT-S7IIKP4gTE0fT7AQ&usg=AFQjCNFC5KkR-IDXBXxJXQaaDAKotyg3Fg) and see if it's really `ArrayBlockingQueue` you want.

Answer (score 0):

The new object was created right here:

```
pool.put(6);
```

It's more obvious when you think what autoboxing is converting that to:

```
pool.put(new Integer(6));
```

The queue neither creates nor reuses these objects, it stores the ones you give it.